# Create CollectionView using .xib?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I want to create CollectionView using .xib file where i will add UICollectionViewCell using .xib too.
Can we achieve it?
If possible, please mention how do we get it.

Comment: Yes you can do it just the same as storyboard. have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike storyboards, .xib files don't support prototype cells. So any collection view you create using a .xib, you must also create a `UINib` and register it with the collection view before attempting to dequeue anything:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible same as storyboards but you will need to register that cell on the collection view On viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourCollectionViewOutlet.register(UINib(nibName: "CellXibName",bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**- Create/drag and drop collectionView to your storyboard.

**Step 2**- Create collectionCell class of type .xib

**Step 3**- Register it using one line code.

```
yourCollectionViewView.register(UINib(nibName: "yourCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier")
```